# Any way to get a currentTime value prior to the seek on HTMLMediaElement?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, webapi

Let's say our app is using the default video player on Safari.

When a user is playing a video and then attempts to move to a different position of the video using the seek bar, it seems like `pause` event is fired first, and then we'll get  `seeking` and `seeked` events fired.

**I am wondering if we can get the `currentTime` value prior to the seek.** For instance, assuming that a user jumps from `t = 7` to `t = 42` using the seek bar, I want to get `7` as the `currentTime` value somehow.

I expected that we could get this value by accessing `currentTime` property inside the `pause` event handler that is invoked right after the seek like the following:

```js
const video = document.querySelector('#myvideo');
video.addEventListener('pause', () => {
  // I expected that the `video.currentTime` here has the "previous" position,
  // but it already points to the new position
  console.log(video.currentTime);
});
```

but unfortunately the `currentValue` was already updated to the new value at that point.

Is there any good way to achieve it?

(EDIT)
Caching `currentTime` manually doesn't help, because apparently a `timeupdate` event fires before a `pause` event. More specifically, taking the following code as an example, when a user attempts to jump to another position, `cache` and `currentTime` printed within the `pause` handler seem always identical.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <video
      id="myvideo"
      width="640"
      height="360"
      controls
      src="video.mp4"
    ></video>
  </body>
  <script>
    const video = document.querySelector("#myvideo");
    let cache = 0;

    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
      cache = video.currentTime;
    });

    video.addEventListener("pause", () => {
      console.log({ cache, currentTime: video.currentTime });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You could always cache it yourself in the timeupdate event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Kaiido! I tried your solution but that didn't work unfortunately. Seems like `timeupdate` happens before `pause`, so cached value is always the same as `video.currentTime`. I just added some code I tried to the post body. Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Then cache two values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Kaiido means this when saying *"Cache two values"*.
Code is untested (but looks better than being kept in comments section)

```
<script>
    const video = document.querySelector("#myvideo");
    let cache = 0;
    let cache_prev = 0;

    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
      cache_prev = cache; //# save last known value
      cache = video.currentTime; //# before updating to new currentTime
    });

    video.addEventListener("pause", () => {
    console.log("cache_prev : " + cache_prev );
    console.log("cache : " + cache );
    console.log("currentTime : " + video.currentTime );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks kinda tricky and workaround-ish but works fine for me actually. I'll go with that.

Comment: Yeah... Workarounds put the "engineering" in software engineering. You've got a system that won't give you the correct time before a Pause event, so cache it yourself manually.